# Ethernet ports not working after re-applying AC power

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, yocto, ethernet

I have a device which runs `yocto` embedded system. The device has `Super Capacitors(supercap)` to provide few mins backup when AC power supply is abruptly pulled off. Please note when device is on `Supercap`, peripherals power are cut to provide little more time to CPU for safe shutdown.

Ethernet ports do not work(not even LED blinks on ports) in following scenarios:

- AC is pulled off so device gets power from `Supercap`(and as result Ethernet ports are abruptly suspended I assumed)
- Re-apply AC power when device is on `supercap` and ethernet ports do not come up again

NOTE: `r8169` kernel driver is being used for ethernet.

There are some suggestions out there to remove and insert `r8169` driver but the driver is an inbuilt module in kernel and I have a feeling that, it is not proper way to fix the problem. There should be some initialization/configuration to fix this.

I also tried couple of commands like "ifconfig enp2s0 up/down" but nothing worked out.

**Edit 1**:
Performed following steps to `unbind/bind` device from driver in `/sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169` directory

- echo -n "0000:02:00.0" > unbind (successful)
- echo -n "0000:02:00.0" > bind (sh: echo: write error: No such device)

**Edit 2**:

This is what `lspci -v -kn` shows about the device after performing `unbind`.

```
02:00.0 0200: 10ec:8168 (rev 15)
    Subsystem: 10ec:0123
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 23
    [virtual] I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    [virtual] Memory at 92104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    [virtual] Memory at 92100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
```

`dmesg` result after issuing `echo -n "0000:02:00.0" > bind`

```
r8169 0000:02:00.0: unknown MAC, using family default
r8169 0000:02:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): rtl_chipcmd_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
libphy: r8169: probed
```

I then tried to remove ethernet interface `enp2s0` and rescan PCI bus using below commands:

- echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.1/0000:02:00.0/remove
- echo 1 > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.1/rescan

Yeeee! I got interface working but it comes with `eth0` instead of `enp2s0`.

I checked boot log and `r8169` seems to be renaming it. Can I rename it without rebooting it?

```
r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth1
```

Comment: I think you are offtopic. Your question is not about programming, or programmer's tools

Comment: Okay, should I ask in super user or somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure. unix and linux SW may be more approriate. But maybe something more on hardware, or network. Possibly google has an idea on where similar questions are sent.

Comment: But have you tried to unbind and bind again? Does it help?

Comment: I am not aware of that, are there any commands/utilities to bind/unbind?, please provide me if you are aware.

Comment: Another point is to switch to better network card, like Intel one, which presumably supports surprise disconnect. Realtek is producing cheap cards and their drivers usually do not support all nice features of the system. I believe you may fix it in the driver.

Comment: `struct dev_pm_ops` for the device driver should point to the code run on resume.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc7/source/include/linux/pm.h#L54

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/

Comment: @stark, what should we understand / learn from your comment? (Mainly I'm interested in the link to the description of the generic PM structure)

Comment: *"as result Ethernet ports are abruptly suspended I assumed"* -- If you are going to *assume* instead of *know*, then solving your problem will be difficult. Ethernet *"ports"* typically consist of two components: the EMAC and PHY.  The PHY is likely a discrete chip, whereas the EMAC could be integrated into the SoC.  Whatever HW loses power should be reset when (full) power is restored, and then has to be reinitialized.

Comment: @sawdust I said "assume" because of I am not sure what is happening with ethernet ports but one thing is sure that they are not working after re-applying AC power.

Comment: @0andriy I have edited question with unbind/bind results.

Comment: *"I am not sure what is happening"* -- If you're going to make an assumption, then test that assumption to determine if it is actually true or false.  You can waste a lot of time & effort trying to solve a problem using false assumptions.  So get a board schematic, and determine how all the components of the Ethernet port(s) are powered in each circumstance.  Review the code, enable debug code, and/or add debug printk()s to learn what happens when the power source is changed.  Your problem is unsolvable with the vague description posted.  All you are getting so far are WAGs.

Comment: @0andriy I would find the pm code, enable debug or add printk as needed, and see whats getting called.

Comment: Okay, it looks like your device is in D3cold. Can you run PCI bus rescan after unbind and try to bind again?

Comment: Also as an alternative you may run `lspci -v -nk` in addition or in replacement to PCI bus rescan and check if it changes anything. Actually output of `lspci` would give some hints.

Comment: @0andriy - Firstly, thanks for constant help. `lspci -v -kn` result updated in question. One difference which I can see is `[virtual]` preceded with couple of fields.

Comment: `udevadm trigger` might help to rename it (I guess it's `systemd` / `udev` which are responsible), but I never dig into this myself. The main point here is that `lspci` most probably calls something to power on the device which is not called otherwise.